# Update src of img dynamically from response json using axios with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, axios

I make an axios post call with an image to a ML backend, it then processes and produce a prediction image and save it to disk and returns the new image's name. the location for these new images to be saved is already pre-set in the backend. so now using the name of the image, I want to update the src attribute of an img in react.

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('qqfile', files[0], files[0].name);
axios.post('http://localhost:5526/upload', fd)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.new_image);
    var path = "/Documents//diabetic_detection/static/processed_file/"+res.data.new_image;
    document.getElementById("result").src = ???
  });
```

files[0] is the image I'm send to the api! res.data.new_image is the name of the processed image. I want to update the src of an img with id 'result' dynamically with this new image. Please help

Comment: Where is your react code? All i see is vanilla JS...

Comment: it's a big file. I just copied the part where I'm having trouble fixing

Comment: Why don't you use react state to update your components when the data came back from the server? Rewriting src with vanilla js functions is not how you do tasks like this in react.